# Running same Airflow DAG with different sets of schedule time

Tags: python, airflow

I am new about airflow here.
I am wondering what's the best way to develop scheduler if I need to run one DAG same logic but with 2 different sets of time.

Case, let's say I have one python DAG file call it `pull_data_from_server.py`:

- I need one scheduler that can run daily to extract data on that specific date.
- I need another scheduler that can run monthly to extract data from date first to last date of month.

Right now, what I do is just make 2 files with same logic however for monthly scheduler I add for loop but this just seems not a good practice because I have 2 files with same logic, if I have any modification made in the future, I need to edit 2 files. Is it possible to just use one DAG file to do this?

pull_data_from_server_daily.py

```
dag = DAG('scheduler_daily', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, 
           schedule_interval='0 0 * * *')

pull_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id="start_pulling_data_from_server",
        python_callable=start_process,
        op_kwargs= {'date" : date_now},
        dag=dag,
    )
```

pull_data_from_server_monthly.py

```
dag = DAG('scheduler_monthly', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, 
           schedule_interval='0 0 1 * *')

for day in last_month:
     pull_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id="start_pulling_data_from_server",
        python_callable=start_process,
        op_kwargs= {'date" : day},
        dag=dag,
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know each DAG can only have 1 scheduling.

You can however create two separate DAGs, one for the daily runs and one for the monthly runs that each use a `TriggerDagRunOperator` that triggers the same DAG in which you define your `PythonOperator`. You can then pass different parameters to this shared DAG (date_now vs day) using the conf. Finally you just have to provide a generic `pull_data_dag` DAG in which you define the PythonOperator as described in your question.

For example:

pull_data_from_server_monthly.py

```
dag = DAG('scheduler_monthly', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval='0 0 1 * *')

for day in last_month:
    monthly_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="monthly_dag",
        trigger_dag_id="pull_data_dag",
        conf={"date": day}
    )
```

pull_data_from_server_daily.py

```
dag = DAG('scheduler_daily', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval='0 0 * * *')

daily_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="daily_dag",
    trigger_dag_id="pull_data_dag",
    conf={"date": date_now}
)
```